# how to pass parameter in a url?

Tags: javascript, php, html

actually i want to pass a parameter in my url and retrieve it in the destination php page. how can i do this?
below is my code:

```html
if($result){
header("Location:view.php",TRUE,$search); 
}
 else{
echo "not found"; 
}
```

is it the correct way to write it? also how can i retrieve the parameter in the destination page that is "view.php"

Comment: just edit it to this `header("Location:view.php?lang=en",TRUE,$search); `

Comment: It makes no sense to put $search as the 3rd parameter to the "header" command - the third parameter is supposed to be the HTTP response code (like 200, or 302, or 500). Did you read the manual page?? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php. Anyway passing parameters is something you would almost certainly cover in tutorials etc. Did you study or research anything? It should be easy to find this information in many many places online. Luckily the answer below has repeated the lesson for you anyway.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you read up general info on [Http request methods first](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp). And maybe [GET and POST comparison](https://www.diffen.com/difference/GET-vs-POST-HTTP-Requests). Also [This](https://code-maven.com/accept-get-and-post-parameters-in-php) explains the accessing params from php

Comment: These are really questions that a beginner tutorial should answer for you, and not us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a variable via the [`GET`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) method:

```
if($result) {
  header("Location: view.php?search={$search}"); 
} else {
  echo "not found"; 
}
```

And then in your destination `view.php` you can access it like this:

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `?` after `view.php` and then the parameters like this `view.php?parameter1=value`.

To access to those parameters in your destination page you have to use this command `$_GET["parameter1"]`

> The GET method sends the encoded user information appended to the page request. The page and the encoded information are separated by the ? character.
>
> - http://www.test.com/index.htm?name1=value1&name2=value2
>     The GET method produces a long string that appears in your server logs, in the browser's Location: box.
> - The GET method is restricted to send upto 1024 characters only.
> - Never use GET method if you have password or other sensitive information to be sent to the server.
> - GET can't be used to send binary data, like images or word documents, to the server.
> - The data sent by GET method can be accessed using QUERY_STRING environment variable.
> - The PHP provides $_GET associative array to access all the sent information using GET method.

This website might be useful for you: [GET&POST methods](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm)
There are some examples you can see to improve your skills.